# changing width of a box inside map function in react js

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to change the size of one of the boxes inside the map function. If all boxes are size of 10px, I want one of the boxes "=" to double the length of other boxes.

CSS:

```
.display-keys {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 10px;
}

.display-equal {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 20px;
}
```

React:

```
const Keys = ({calcKeys})=>(
  <div> 
   {calcKeys.map(item=>
     {item.key} !== "=" ?
       <button className="display-keys">{item.key}</button> :
       <button className="display-equal">{item.key}</button>
   )} 
 </div>)

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state={
     calcKeys:[{"key": "AC"},{"key": "CE"},{"key": "±"},{"key": "="}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    };
    render(){
     return(
      <div className="display-container">
       <Keys calcKeys={this.state.calcKeys}/>
      </div> 
    )
  }
  ReactDOM......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{calcKeys.map((item)=>{
    if(item.key !== '='){
       return <button className="display-keys">{item.key}</button>
    }
    return <button className="display-equal">{item.key}</button>
  })
}
```

Comment: It's working for me. Here is the codepen, https://codepen.io/wbh24/pen/yLyXgbW

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You should return the result of the map function

```
 {calcKeys.map(item=>{ 
    return (item.key !== "=") ?
       <button className="display-keys">{item.key}</button> :
       <button className="display-equal">{item.key}</button>
     }
    ) 
  }
```

next:

> The grid-template-columns CSS property defines the line names and track sizing functions >of the grid columns.

In your CSS, use `width` for the length of boxes

```
.display-keys {
      width: 40px;
              }

.display-equal {
      width: 80px;
             }
```

you don't need put `display: grid` inside those files. I think you already have it in `.display-container`

and finally, you can check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-haze-bdwkt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) out.